# How to read python files from a directory and search for functions

Tags: python, function, search, pyqt, qcombobox

I am looking to make a dictionary of python file names as the value and the functions defined in each file as the key. I am easily able to make a list of the filenames. For example:

```
    for child in Path('./loaders').iterdir():
        if child.is_file():
            f = child.name
            if f != "__init__.py":
                self.beamline_options.append(f.split('.')[0])
```

I also have a variable defined as `self.beamline_loaders = {}`, which I would like to add to this loop above in such a way:

```
    for child in Path('./loaders').iterdir():
        if child.is_file():
            f = child.name
            if f != "__init__.py":
                self.beamline_options.append(f.split('.')[0])
                self.beamline_loaders[f] = [def1, def2, def3, ...]
```

where def1, def2, ... would be the names of the functions in each file. All of this is within the same module. I am using this dictionary to populate a QComboBox based on the selection of a first combo-box (which consists of just the names in the list of beamline options). This could in theory be hard coded, but I would prefer not to hard code it.

Comment: So, your purpose would be to have something like `A.py` with `functionX()` and `B.py` with `functionY()` and `functionZ()`, with the result being something like calling `functionX('A')`, `functionY('B')` or `functionZ('B')` depending on the combo value? If that's the general idea, it's a ***terrible*** idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a simple plugin system that can dynamically load functions from any python files found in a target directory. Presumably, you will also need to *execute* those functions at some point, rather than just display their names. In which case, one solution would be to use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) to directly import the modules from the source files, and then use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to scan the module's attributes for suitable function objects.

Below is a basic demo that implements that, and also shows how to populate some combo-boxes with the module and function names. The function objects themselves are loaded on demand and stored in a `dict`, and can be displayed via the "Load" button. (NB: the demo assumes that the "loaders" directory is in the same directory as the demo script):

[image: screenshot]

```
import sys, types, importlib.util
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

BASEDIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.joinpath('loaders')

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.buttonLoad = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Load')
        self.buttonLoad.clicked.connect(self.handleLoad)
        self.comboOptions = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboOptions.currentTextChanged.connect(self.handleOptions)
        self.comboLoaders = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboOptions)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboLoaders)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLoad)
        self.scanOptions()

    def scanOptions(self):
        self.beamline_options = {}
        self.beamline_loaders = defaultdict(dict)
        for entry in BASEDIR.iterdir():
            if entry.is_file() and entry.match('[!_.]*.py'):
                self.beamline_options[entry.stem] = entry
        self.comboOptions.addItems(self.beamline_options)

    def getLoaders(self, option):
        if option not in self.beamline_loaders:
            entry = self.beamline_options[option]
            modname = f'{BASEDIR.name}.{option}'
            spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(modname, entry)
            module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            sys.modules[modname] = module
            spec.loader.exec_module(module)
            for name in dir(module):
                if not name.startswith('_'):
                    obj = getattr(module, name)
                    if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
                        self.beamline_loaders[option][name] = obj
        return self.beamline_loaders[option]

    def getLoader(self, option, loader):
        if option and loader:
            return self.getLoaders(option)[loader]

    def handleOptions(self, option):
        self.comboLoaders.clear()
        self.comboLoaders.addItems(self.getLoaders(option))

    def handleLoad(self):
        option = self.comboOptions.currentText()
        loader = self.comboLoaders.currentText()
        func = self.getLoader(option, loader)
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Load', repr(func))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 400, 50)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible means of doing this would be to use the `ast` module built in to python.

With the ast module you could read a python file and parse it into individual python language tokens, and collect the ones that identify as function definitions.

for example:

```
import ast

def parse_file(path):
    source = path.read_text()
    tree = ast.parse(source)
    top_level = []
    for stmt in ast.iter_child_nodes(tree):
        if isinstance(stmt, ast.FunctionDef) or isinstance(stmt, ast.ClassDef):
            top_level.append(stmt.name)
    return top_level
    
for child in Path('./loaders').iterdir():
    if child.is_file() and child.suffix == ".py":
        if child.name != "__init__.py":
            self.beamline_options.append(child.name.split('.')[0])
            self.beamline_loaders[child.name] = parse_file(child)
```